# RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() is null sometimes

Tags: java, spring

In my Java Spring project I use

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                                         .getRequestAttributes())
                                         .getRequest();
```

which defined in a static method to get request and get some session attributes. spring-RequestContextListener is already exist in my web.xml. The question is when some single thread invoke that, everything is fine for now.

But when using java8 parallelStream, `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` can be  null sometimes and I do not know why.

Comment: I figured that parallelStream use ThreadLocal to execute threads, and it is not variable thread spreaded. Explained the question.

Comment: any idea how to get access to the request object from within a that thread?

Comment: @Hamid You need to assign request/session to a static Object. But it is better not using parallelStream to do some biz logic.

Answer (score 1):

Is your project spring or spring boot?
if it is spring boot, expose a bean with either RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter

```
@Bean
  public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
    return new RequestContextListener();
  }
```

also make sure you don't have any @Configuration classes anotated with @EnableWebMvc. this will remove spring boot autoconfiguration cababilities.